# How many vertices does a complete binary tree of height 1 have?

Tags: trees

1. How many vertices does a complete binary tree of height 1 has?
2. Height 2?
3. Height d?

Any hints on how to start to tackle these set of questions?

Comment: Start by looking up the definitions of "complete binary tree" and "height".

Comment: Okay, so a binary tree with a height of one would have three rows. I binary tree with a height of 2 would have 3 rows and a binary tree of height d would have (d+1)  rows.  What should I look in to next?  I understand vertices, but I am just referring to the general set? If so, I think  height 1 would have 2 vertices, height 2 would have 6 vertices, but I do not know about height d.  I would imagine it would be d to some power.

Comment: Work induction from your base cases, @Natasha.

Comment: A perfect binary tree of height $1$ has two levels, not three: it has a root with two daughter vertices.

Answer (score 4):

For definitions of height and complete binary tree, see [Binary Trees](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/15-121/lectures/Trees/trees.html). It is worth noting that the definition of complete binary tree may allow for more leaves to be added at the lowest level. Strictly speaking it is a *perfect* binary tree has all leaves present at the lowest level: you need to clarify whether your question is really referring to a perfect binary tree.

To find the number of vertices in a perfect binary tree of height $h$, on paper

- draw a perfect binary tree of height 1, and count the number of vertices
- draw a perfect binary tree of height 2, and count the number of vertices
- and so on...
- ... and see if you can spot a pattern.

You may find the [sum of a geometric series](http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/sequences-sums-geometric.html) useful in turning the pattern into a formula.

If you do need to find the number of vertices in a not necessarily perfect, complete binary tree, this is at most the number of vertices in a perfect binary tree of the same height, and has to be greater than the number of vertices in a perfect binary tree of one less height.